# PHP - Pass GET variable from parent page to iframe

Tags: php, session, variables, iframe

I have this parent page:

parentpage.php?rentalid=10

And on that page I have an iframe. In that iframe, I need to be able to write some code relative to the "rentalid" on the parent page's url. For example, I'd like to write:

```
<? if ($_GET['rentalid']==10) { ?>
code
<? } ?>
```

When I write it like that now inside the iframe, it doesn't recognize the "rentalid" variable. So how can I pass it from the parent page to the iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We pass `rentalid` in any case, if it's 10 or more, because it's better to check that id in the page of iframe.

```
<iframe src="iframe/page.php?rentalid=<?=isset($_GET['rentalid']) ? $_GET['rentalid'] : '' ?>" width="300" height="400"></iframe>
```

Here `isset` checks if `rentalid` is provided by the user for parent page, without it php would throw an error for undefined index for `rentalid`

Answer (score 1):

First one . you should check whether landing page is received that variable or not. I think you can't get value of variable in landing page.

according to me you should do it for check. run it on your landing page.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['rentalid'])) // Use REQUEST for global
{
      if(($_REQUEST['rentalid']) == '10')
            echo " You are getting rental id";
      else
            echo " Your rental id is not 10";
}
else
   echo "You can't get value of Rental id";
```